# What does ウ○ク mean in ウ○クの方の、中○、韓○嫌いは異常。?

Tags: meaning, words, definitions

So, I was looking on [OKWAVE](https://okwave.jp/searchkeyword?word=%E5%A4%96%E5%9B%BD%E4%BA%BA%E5%AB%8C%E6%82%AA), because I wanted to know if anyone is asking about xenophobia in Japan.

So there is a question asking, “外国人嫌悪症について、どう思いますか？” This can be translated as “What do you think about xenophobia?”

In one of the responses to this question, it discusses hatred between countries and how extreme it can get. It brings up the following sentence: “ウ○クの方の、中○、韓○嫌いは異常。”

I am pretty sure that ○ is a censorship symbol. I heard that there is pretty extreme hatred between Japan and China as well as Japan and both Koreas, but I didn't think it got to the point of partly censoring the names of those countries in Japanese.

I think the sentence says something like, “Their hatred for people of ???, China, and South Korea is unusual.”

Does anyone have a clue what ウ○ク means?

Comment: By the way 外国人嫌悪 is not a very natural word to translate "xenophobia". You can find more topics in the same search box e.g. [when you input 排外](https://okwave.jp/searchkeyword?word=%E6%8E%92%E5%A4%96).

Comment: Here is a good service for identifying partially censored words: http://fuseji.net/%E3%82%A6%E2%97%8B%E3%82%AF

Comment: @broccoliforest: Is that right? It's just that 外国人嫌悪 is the title of the “Xenophobia” article on the Japanese Wikipedia. Oh, dear. I wonder why that is the title, if that is not a natural word for translation.

Comment: @MichealGignac You know, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matricaria_chamomilla) is not a natural word what we call the flower, right?

Comment: @broccoliforest: Oh, I see! So it's the technical term, and not the term people would use in everyday conversation! Now I get it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's 「ウヨク」,「[右翼]{うよく}」 "the right wing".

> ウヨクの方の、中国、韓国嫌いは異常。

"The right wingers' hatred toward China and Korea is unusual/insane."

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help! I should have suspected! I have heard stories told about Japanese right-wing groups and Internet right-wingers, but since most of them are in English, I suspect that they barely scratch the surface of the situation.